# Vue // this.$root.$off unsubscribes all instances of the component from the global event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom input validation component that I use in a form. Something like 15 instances of this component around the app. It has a `beforeDestroy` method in which I unsubscribe from global event called `triggerGlobalValidation` which triggers validation before I send request to server. As expected it's triggered only once inside this certain component.

There is a container with `v-if` parameter which contains one instance of the component. So when `v-if="false"` I expect this certain component to unsubscribe from event and get destroyed.  It goes well accept for one thing: somehow this component unsubscribes **ALL** other instances of it from the `triggerGlobalValidation` event as well.

I've tested the behavior with `v-show` and it works as expected - all other instances keep subscribed, but since the `v-show` field is required for the form it's blocking validation even without being shown in the DOM. I also tested above mentioned components behavior by removing the `this.$root.$off("triggerGlobalValidation")` and it also works as expected + polluting the global root.

*Vue documentation on $off method is saying:*

> If no arguments are provided, remove all event listeners;
>
> If only the event is provided, remove all listeners for that event;
>
> If both event and callback are given, remove the listener for that
>   specific callback only.

Is it possible to somehow mention in the callback, that this `$off` method shouldn't unsubscribe **all** of its instances from the event, but just this **certain** one being destroyed?

Check it out in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrk25l907l)

Comment: it is right there in the docs, pass the second argument. this.$root.$off('triggerGlobalValidation', yourHandler)

Comment: So what kind of handler should it be? The only thing I need is to unsibscribe destroyed element from the event

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As answered in the issue, you need to save the handler and pass it again to `$off`

```js
mounted() {
  this.fn = () => {
    this.toggleWarning();
  }
  this.$root.$on("triggerChildComponents", this.fn);
},
beforeDestroy() {
  this.$root.$off("triggerChildComponents", this.fn);
},
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Appeared that this approach doesn't work until you add handlers (and unsubscribe from them) for all other components, subscribed to the same event.